# Pandas fail to read excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to read an Excel file using Pandas by:

```
dataSet = pd.read_excel(xlsPath, encoding = 'utf-8')
```

but got this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xa4' in position 15353: character maps to <undefined>
```

I there any way I can fix that?

P.S. That's the [excel file](https://github.com/Amarthgul/PersonalCodes/blob/master/EDUTL1902/Data.xlsx) I'm working on

Comment: Redownload  the file and try again...

Comment: Hello, on a Mac with pandas `0.20.3` it works without any option `pd.read_excel(xlsPath)`. What is your pandas version and OS?

Comment: `pd.read_excel('https://github.com/Amarthgul/PersonalCodes/raw/master/EDUTL1902/Data.xlsx')` pandas 0.23.4 xlrd 1.1.0 read without an issue on Win7. Check you versions?

Comment: @Romain Gosh I updated pandas, now it works... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to download the thing directly, passing `?raw=true`. Works fine for me!

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://github.com/Amarthgul/PersonalCodes/blob/master/EDUTL1902/Data.xlsx?raw=true'
df = pd.read_excel(url, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

The file isn't utf-8 encoded. You need to figure out what the encoding is.

Personally I'd give `dataSet = pd.read_excel(xlsPath, encoding="ISO-8859-1")` a shot first.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers I see posted. Resave the file as a .xlsx and it should load fine. It worked for me.